# How could I initialize a two dimensional char pointer in C++ class

Tags: c++, pointers, char

```
class Tool
{
public:
    Tool();
    ~Tool();

private:
    char **s;
};

char *s1[]={"hello","world"};
```

How can I initialize `s` and make it same as `s1`?

```
s={"hello","world"}
```

doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @Anguslilei `char **s;` this isn't a 2D array, this is a pointer to a pointer.

Comment: A total guess, `std::vector<std::string>>`

Comment: You never should. You should use a vector of strings.

Comment: What if I don't want to use vector, Is there any way that I could declare s in class Tool. Thank you all!

Comment: When you say you don't want to use a vector, is there a particular reason you don't want to? Strings will be much easier to manage in a vector as compared to a array of pointers to string arrays, so unless you have an incredibly good reason to not use a vector, you should do that.

Comment: Because I use a API that developed by others. One of the  API function parameter is char** arg.If I use s1, it works well but I really don't know how I could define s in class Tool.@RyanP

Comment: In the embedded world, using STL components is often not recommended because dynamic allocation is problematic on devices with low amounts of RAM.

Answer (score 1):

While you could use a `std::vector<std::string>`, I feel it's more beneficial to you to directly answer your question.

`char** s` is a pointer to a pointer; possibly a pointer to the first pointer in an array of pointers.

`char* s1[]` is an array of pointers to const data (and should have actually been made `const`).

If you want `s` to work similarly to `s1`, you first need to allocate the array of pointers, which is the reason `std::vector` was recommended by others. You could do it yourself with `new`, but you have to release the allocated memory at some point. Using `new` directly is prone to leaks. `std::vector` will release its allocated memory when the object is destructed. You too could call `delete[]` in your destructor if you wanted to.

When your array has been allocated, you then need to `std::copy` the array of pointers in `s1` to the array of pointers in `s`. It's not a single assign operation.

Comment: It seems hard for s working similarly to s1.  Now, I  know the difference between s and s1 and thank you all guys very much!

Comment: And therein lies the reason others recommended std::vector<std::string> :)